# How to build JSP/JSF like UiBinder tags in GWT?

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I've used JSP tag libs, freemarker, tiles, JSF-Facelets extensively in the past. Similar to their use of taglibs, is there anyway I could do the following in GWT UiBinder:

1) Composition: create a tag library in UiBinder (no java code) and include the tag into another uiBinder file
2) Inheritance: create a base layout UiBinder file (master layoyut) and override specific content areas in child UiBinder files?
3) Pass clientside variables into UiBinder ($(map.property))

In general, I'm not sure how UiBinder compares with other templating libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To insert a content of one page in another with UiBinder create a class `mypackage.Header` together with a file `Header.ui.xml` in the same package `mypackage`. Then your UiBinder holder-file should look like this:

```
<ui:UiBinder 
    xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
    xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'
    xmlns:my='urn:import:mypackage'>

  <g:HTMLPanel>
    <my:Header />
    <!-- other content  -->
  </g:HTMLPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

In the first place UiBinder is a very convenient tool for separating UI from its behavior. In addition it helps productivity(it's true!), maintainability, and has other features.
UiBinder in GWT is very different from JSF approach. This tool isn't a render. In contrast to JSF it not contain any loops or condition. There are no `if` statements in its markup and only a very limited expression language. All the logic is in Java class. And rightly so. It's logical to have loops and conditionals in the class than in view.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Turns out gwt sample project, Mail, has code that demonstrates the above. So, does GWT automagically figure out the namespace based on the naming convention?

Comment: Is there a way to extend UiBinder and the corresponding Generator class, add a custom annotation like @UiData in the composite component implementation and expose it in UiBinder like my:header data="12343"? If you know how a "value" is injected in a facelet JSF page for datatables, listboxes etc., then that's what I'm asking for.

Answer (score 0):

UiBinder is not a templating tool. The idea is that XML is easier to read and maintain than Java.

UiRenderer (GWT 2.5) and SafeHtmlTemplates are, but they're quite basic. They answer your 3rd point only.

GWT doesn't answer your first two points.

Comment: If you can't compose tags, how does UiBinder scale and aggregate/integrate other components built using UiBinder? Do users have to build a single monolithic 10,000 line xml file?

Comment: No, it's poor practice because such structure is hard to maintain. You can to create one UiBinder-document and include it in other UiBinder-document. Here you can find some analogy with `ui:insert` in JSF.

Comment: @pritam: UiBinder is an implementation detail of a widget; componentization is about building widgets (possibly with UiBinder) and assembling them (possibly with UiBinder).